# Can't force a script not to print error log details in the console

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, seleniumwire

I'm trying to create a script using python in combination with [seleniumwire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) implementing poxies within it. The script sometimes works correctly but most of the time comes up with error log details even when the status_code is 200. ***I wish to get rid of those log details***. The ip address that is hardcoded within the script is taken from a free proxy site, so it might not be of any use at this moment.

This is what I'm trying with:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

URL = 'https://www.zillow.com/Houston,-TX/houses/'

options = {
    'mitm_http2': False,
    'proxy': {'https': f'https://136.226.33.115:80'}
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get(URL)
assert driver.requests[0].response.status_code==200
post_links = [i.get_attribute("href") for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("article[role='presentation'] > .list-card-info > a.list-card-link")]
for individual_link in post_links:
    driver.get(individual_link)
    assert driver.requests[0].response.status_code==200
    post_title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1").text
    print(post_title)
driver.quit()
```

This is the type of error log details I can see in the console:

```
127.0.0.1:55825: request
  -> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected
127.0.0.1:55967: request
  -> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected
127.0.0.1:64891: request
  -> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected
127.0.0.1:61466: request
  -> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected
127.0.0.1:51332: request
  -> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected
127.0.0.1:52783: request
  -> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected
```

> How can I force the script not to print those log details?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly but if you only want to get rid of the log lines why avoid to log those cases with a simple if sentence. Otherwise if you want to catch these errors you might want to add another assertion so post_title do not contains the error message:  assert 'Server disconnected' not in post_title

Comment: I don't understand which portion of the above post is unclear to you @pafede2. I kicked out `assert` and used `if` statement as you suggested. I also added the line containing `Server disconnected` but the error is still there. I just can't figure out where the heck those error log come from. I never encountered such error when I used `selenium` instead of `seleniumwire`.

Comment: What is the full log line that you see? Not only the details!

Comment: Check [this](https://filebin.varnish-software.com/jjnejl9tm81mi73g/stacktrace.txt) out @rfkortekaas. The script gets disconnected (which you can see in the log) after one successful loop as I used a single proxy. However, when the proxies are working ones, this stuff always `-> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected` keeps coming up.

Comment: Can you try it with adding `chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])` as `chrome_options=chrome_options` to `webdriver.Chrome()` where `chrome_options` is `Options()` from `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options`

Comment: When I tried like this `options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])`, I got this error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'` as I've defined proxies in a dict within the same `options` just before that line. However, I tried like this `options["excludeSwitches"] = ['enable-logging']` but I see that error `-> HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected` still coming up.

Comment: Which versions do you use (chrome, chromedriver, selenium and seleniumwire)? If I do the following (replace ; for newline) it's not giving any logging on stdout: `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options; chrome_options = Options()
; chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']); chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work eiter. My python version `3.7` and selenium version is `3.141.0`. According to this [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/), It seems that I need to have `Selenium 3.4.0+`. Can you suggest how can I upgrade selenium version to `3.4+`?

Answer (score 2):

You can define the desired log error level by the following code line:

```
options .add_argument('--log-level=3')
```

Add this to your `options`.

log-level attribute sets the minimum log level.
Valid values are from 0 to 3:

INFO = 0,
WARNING = 1,
LOG_ERROR = 2,
LOG_FATAL = 3.

default is 0.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but that didn't work out. In fact that was my first attempt to suppress those errors before posing the question. I tried all your provided options by the way.

Comment: maybe it's just a different syntax? I see you used different syntax for what you defined in `options` in your code. So maybe you should just match syntaxes? Currently I see no additional ways to do that.

Comment: Syntax is not the issue here. I used them correctly. FYI, this is the right syntax `c_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')` and finally `webdriver.Chrome(options=c_options,seleniumwire_options=options)`

Comment: I know what I wrote is with correct syntax,  but you used some other syntax in your code `options = {
    'mitm_http2': False,
    'proxy': {'https': f'https://136.226.33.115:80'}
}`

Comment: You forgot to go through my last comment. This is how you can use two type of options in there `webdriver.Chrome(options=c_options,seleniumwire_options=options)`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Actually I'm using Java so I do not really familiar with these details in Python :)

Answer (score 2):

### ORIGINAL POST 06-22-2021 @12:00 UTC

The error:

```
HTTP protocol error in client request: Server disconnected
```

Is being thrown by *mitmproxy.*  I pulled the following from *mitmproxy* source code.

```
"clientconnect": "client_connected",
"clientdisconnect": "client_disconnected",
"serverconnect": "server_connect and server_connected",
"serverdisconnect": "server_disconnected",


class ServerDisconnectedHook(commands.StartHook):
    """
    A server connection has been closed (either by us or the server).
    """
    blocking = False
    data: ServerConnectionHookData
```

I would recommend putting your code in a Try Except block, which will allow you to suppress the errors thrown by *mitmproxy*.

```
from mitmproxy.exceptions import MitmproxyException
from mitmproxy.exceptions import HttpReadDisconnect

try:
  your driver code
except HttpReadDisconnect as e:
    pass
except MitmproxyException as e:
    """
    Base class for all exceptions thrown by mitmproxy.
    """
    pass
finally:
  driver.quit()
```

If the exceptions that I provided don't suppress your error than I would recommend trying some of the other Exceptions in *mitmproxy*.

[image]

### UPDATE 06-22-2021 @15:28 UTC

In my research I noted that *seleniumwire* has integration code with *mitmproxy.* Part of this integration is capturing error message thrown by *mitmproxy."

```
class SendToLogger:

    def log(self, entry):
        """Send a mitmproxy log message through our own logger."""
        getattr(logger, entry.level.replace('warn', 'warning'), logger.info)(entry.msg)
```

In my testing suppressing the error in question using *mitmproxy.exceptions* is difficult.  In testing the following exceptions, the only one that fired was *HttpReadDisconnect.* And that firing wasn't consistent.

- HttpException
- HttpReadDisconnect
- HttpProtocolException
- Http2ProtocolException
- MitmproxyException
- ServerException
- TlsException

I noted that if I added a standard *Exception:*

```
except Exception as error:
    print('standard')
    print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__)))
```

That this line in your code consistently throws errors:

```
 File "/Users/user_name/Python_Projects/scratch_pad/seleniumwire_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    assert driver.requests[0].response.status_code == 200
```

When I looked at this error in more detail I found that it was related to the *status_code.*

```
<class 'AttributeError'>
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

### UPDATE 06-23-2021 @15:04 UTC

During my research I found that *selenium* had a *service_log_path*   parameter that could be added to *webdriver.Chrome()*.

```
class WebDriver(ChromiumDriver):
   
    def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=DEFAULT_PORT,
                 options: Options = None, service_args=None,
                 desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=DEFAULT_SERVICE_LOG_PATH,
                 chrome_options=None, service: Service = None, keep_alive=DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE):
```

According to the documentation this parameter could be used this way: *service_log_path=/dev/null*

Unfortunately, the comments in *class WebDriver(ChromiumDriver)* indicated that this parameter is deprecated.  It also failed to suppress the *sys.stdout* error messages.

> service_log_path - Deprecated: Where to log information from the driver.

### CURRENT STATUS

I reworked your code and removed the *status_code* lines that were throwing errors.  I added some *implicitly_wait()* and some *WebDriverWait* statements to handle what you were trying to do with the *status_code* statement. I also added some error handling to catch specific error message types.  And I added some *chrome_options* to suppress certain things, such a loading website images, which are not needed for scraping the target website.

Finally, I added a custom logging feature to suppress the error messages that were being sent to the *sys.stdout*.  I tested the code many times and so far I haven't received and error message to *sys.stdout*.  More testing might be needed it you get the messages again.

Here is a [link](https://filebin.varnish-software.com/6vgrm7fs4brsnzad) of the code in action.

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from mitmproxy.exceptions import HttpReadDisconnect, TcpDisconnect, TlsException


class DisableLogger():
    def __enter__(self):
       logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
    def __exit__(self, exit_type, exit_value, exit_traceback):
       logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)


options = {
    "backend": "mitmproxy",
    'mitm_http2': False,
    'disable_capture': True,
    'verify_ssl': True,
    'connection_keep_alive': False,
    'max_threads': 3,
    'connection_timeout': None,
    'proxy': {
        'https': 'https://209.40.237.43:8080',
    }
}

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-application-cache")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts'] = True

prefs = {
   "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,
   "profile.default_content_settings.images": 2
 }

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',
                          options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=options)

with DisableLogger():
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    try:
        driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/Houston,-TX/houses/')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 240)
        page_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-page-react-content"]')))
        if page_title:
            post_links = [i.get_attribute("href") for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("article[role='presentation'] > .list-card-info > a.list-card-link")]
            for individual_link in post_links:
                driver.implicitly_wait(60)
                driver.get(individual_link)
                post_title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1").text
                print(post_title)

    except HttpReadDisconnect as error:
        print('A HttpReadDisconnect Exception has occurred')
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        print(exc_type)
        print(exc_value)
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__)))
        driver.quit()

    except TimeoutException as error:
        print('A TimeOut Exception has occurred')
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        print(exc_type)
        print(exc_value)
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__)))
        driver.quit()

    except TcpDisconnect as error:
        print('A TCP Disconnect Exception has occurred')
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        print(exc_type)
        print(exc_value)
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__)))
        driver.quit()

    except TlsException as error:
        print('A TLS Exception has occurred')
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        print(exc_type)
        print(exc_value)
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__)))
        driver.quit()

    except Exception as error:
        print('An exception has occurred')
        print(''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__)))
        pass

    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

### OBSERVATIONS

I noted that you are using free proxies instead of paid proxy service.  The proxy in your code *hxxps://136.226.33.115:80* I found was a standard HTTP proxy and it also was having latency issues, which was causing timeouts when connecting to your target website.

Another observation is that your target website has captcha, which are fired when you send too many connection requests.

I also noted that your proxy server would also have connection issues, which would cause error messages to be sent to *sys.stdout*. This is what you were likely encountering.

### SIDE NOTE

The selenium session in your code occasionally encounters an *I am human* captcha from Zillow.

[image]

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------

Platform: Mac 
Python Version: 3.9
Seleniumwire: 4.3.1
Selenium: 3.141.0
mitmproxy: 6.0.2
browserVersion: 91.0.4472.114
chromedriverVersion: 90.0.4430.24
IDE: PyCharm 2021.1.2

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Honestly speaking, I chose `seleniumwire` only to be able to use this line `driver.requests[0].response.status_code == 200` to get the status. Pure Selenium doesn't offer anything of that sort to check the status code.

Comment: You can check the status code with selenium.  If need I can provide that code to you.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Seleniumwire will be of no use to me then.

Comment: @SMTH Please let me know if you have any questions about the code that I posted in the *Current Status* section of my answer.

Comment: [This](https://filebin.varnish-software.com/hy2m4ii4khejdexs) is what I experience when I execute your script. I ran the script twice to be sure that what I saw is real. To be specific, the error is still there and I could see neumerous windows opened at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: I have never seen those error happen before in my testing, so it is related to your environment.   Take at look at my system information that I posted.  Also I alway used an *executable_path* for my *chromedriver*.

Comment: I posted a video link in my answer of my code in action.  It throw no error messages.

Comment: Looks like it is working perfectly fine on your end. I didn't include chomedriver path within the script only because the path is already added to the environment.

Comment: It is working perfectly on my system.  Can you please share your system information in your question?

Comment: I'm on Win 7, 32 bit. My python version 3.7 and selenium version is 3.141.0.

Comment: What is your browserVersion and chromedriverVersion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234132/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-smth).

Answer (score 1):

if you are working in a linux distribution, you can redirect error outputs. to do so, you should add `2>/dev/null` to the end of your command.
for example, you can run your script like this:

```
python SCRIPT 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I'm on windows 7, 32 bit.